# "Hello World" not compiling due to "return(0)"?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, return, return-value, function-definition

simple question:

why does my code compile when it looks like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void hello()
{
    write (1, "3", 3);
    
}

int main ()
{
    hello();
}
```

Output: 3

And why does it not compile when I add `return(0);` in the line after `write (1, "3", 3);` ?

The error message I get is:

```
2function.c:7:2: error: void function 'hello' should not return a value [-Wreturn-type]
        return(0);
```

Thanks!

Comment: `void()` functions do not return a value. Compiler error is pretty clear.

Comment: If you drop `<unistd.h>` and output with `printf("3");` your program is *much* more portable to all environments with a C compiler (Windows, online compilers, Smart fridge, Lunar Lander, Klingon space ship, ...); not just environments with POSIX interface.

Answer (score 3):

A function with a return type of `void` means that it returns no value.  So if such a function uses a `return` statement with a value, that violates the definition of the function.

It's also not advisable to fail to return a value from a function with a return type other than `void`, even though compilers will allow it.  The `main` function however is an exception.  If no value is returned from `main`, the return value is assumed to be 0.

Comment: Re “If no value is returned from `main`, the return value is assumed to be 0”: Specifically, if control reaches the closing `}` of `main`, zero is returned. If no value is returned from `main` because it does not return (e.g., continues indefinitely), there is no return value.

Answer (score 3):

`void` means nothing. When your function return type is void, you shouldn't return anything. Or you can write only `return;`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your function

```
void hello()
```

is defined as type "void" - that is, you're defining it as something that does not return anything. You can add

```
return;
```

to the end, but only because it's not returning a value. if you would like to return 0 in function "hello" you would need to declare the data type you would like to return, instead of void, ie.

```
int hello()
```

that will then allow you to return any int, such as return 0;

Answer (score 1):

You declared hello to return "void", which is to say nothing at all, yet you are trying to return 0.

Answer (score 1):

For starters this call

```
write (1, "3", 3);
```

invokes undefined behavior at least because the string literal `"3"` contains only 2 characters (not `3` as you think) that is it is stored as a character array as `{ '3', '\0' }`.

You declared the function `hello` as having the return type `void`. Such a function shall not return a value.

From the C Standard (6.8.6.4 The return statement)

> 1 **A return statement with an expression shall not appear in a
> function whose return type is void.** A return statement without an
> expression shall only appear in a function whose return type is void.

So the compiler issues an error relative to your inserted statement

```
return(0);
```

Instead you could just write

```
return;
```

though it does not make a great sense for such a function containing only one statement.

It seems you wanted to insert the statement

```
return(0);
```

in `main` like

```
int main( void )
{
    hello();

    return 0;    
}
```

though in `main` it may be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

void means return nothing when you declare the function as void you cant return anything. but if you want to return something change the return type to `int,float` etc

Answer (score 0):

To return anything from function you must specify the return type before function name. void means nothing and you are trying to return an integer from hello(). That's why you are getting error.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h
int hello(){
   write (1, "3", 3);
   return 0; 
}

int main (){
    hello();
    return 0;
}
```